# Is there a way to know if an observer did / did not get a notification from NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

`ViewController.m` is registered as an observer in `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` and it's working. But `ViewController` does X inside `viewDidLoad` method.

I would like X to happen **only** if `ViewController` **did not** get the notification.

The architecture might sound broken indeed, but my question is if there is some data inside `defaultCenter` the tells us if an observer got a notification?

Comment: That design sounds broken and it sounds like you might want to look into direct delegation instead of notification broadcasting - I would consider notifications "fire-and-forget"

Comment: you are right, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no call-back methods for us to know if the sended `notification` if is recieved by the observer.

According to the `Notification Center` methods we can get in Xcode:

```
/****************   Notification Center ****************/
open class NotificationCenter : NSObject {


    open class var `default`: NotificationCenter { get }


    open func addObserver(_ observer: Any, selector aSelector: Selector, name aName: NSNotification.Name?, object anObject: Any?)


    open func post(_ notification: Notification)

    open func post(name aName: NSNotification.Name, object anObject: Any?)

    open func post(name aName: NSNotification.Name, object anObject: Any?, userInfo aUserInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil)


    open func removeObserver(_ observer: Any)

    open func removeObserver(_ observer: Any, name aName: NSNotification.Name?, object anObject: Any?)


    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    open func addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, object obj: Any?, queue: OperationQueue?, using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Swift.Void) -> NSObjectProtocol
}
```

And we can refer to `NotificationCenter`'s [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter) , we should learn its function is：

> Objects register with a notification center to receive notifications (NSNotification objects) using the addObserver(_:selector:name:object:) or addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:) methods.

And from docs can not find any mention of your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a call back, consider Combine, which works more like a transactional communications protocol.